# Facultatif ou non ? (ne et l')

Tags: usage

Dans les phrases ci-dessous

> D'autres noms ne sont pas ordinairement précédés d'un déterminant, mais ils peuvent **l'être** dans certains cas.

et

> Les differences entre le masculin et le féminin sont plus importantes
>   que **ne l'indique** l'écriture.

l' (dans l'être et dans l'indique) est-il la forme élidée de le ? Ce l' est-il facultatif ou non ?
En plus, **ne** (dans ne l'indique) est-il facultatif on non ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*L'* est bien la forme élidée de *le* (ce ne peut pas être autre chose).

Dans la première phrase, *l'* est obligatoire. J'en suis sûr en tant que locuteur natif, mais je ne suis pas sûr de l'explication grammaticale. Je crois que c'est parce que sans complément, le verbe change de sens : « ils peuvent être dans certains cas » voudrait dire « ils peuvent exister dans certains cas » et sonne bizarre.

Dans la deuxième, je le mettrais. Mon intuition bloque quand j'essaie de savoir s'il est obligatoire. Même si « l'écriture indique » n'est pas une phrase complète, on comprend la phrase sans *l'*. Le *ne* est obligatoire en langue soutenue et facultatif en langue moins soutenue, mais comme c'est une tournure très soutenue, il est quasiment obligatoire dans cette phrase. On peut donc peut-être écrire « … que n'indique l'écriture » mais pas vraiment « … que l'indique l'écriture ». Omettre les deux (« … qu'indique l'écriture ») pose un problème parce que *que* a plusieurs fonctions grammaticales possibles et la phrase devient difficile à comprendre si on peut croire que c'est un pronom relatif qui est complément d'objet direct du verbe *indique* : on a l'impression que l'écriture indique les différences.

J'aurais tendance à tourner la deuxième phrase autrement (de façon un peu moins soutenue) : « les différences […] sont plus importantes que ce qu'indique l'écriture » (aucun mot n'est facultatif).